# javascript hover function for submenu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm pretty new at trying to understand javascript and I've been pooling over multiple examples trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but cant get this working properly.  At one point I had working with onmouseover/mouseout but it only worked on 1 of the menus.

I'm sure it is something simple I have overlooked, but any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/N3TyT/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#top-menu').hover(
  function () {
    $('#submenu').show(active);
  },
  function () {
    $('#submenu').hide(non-active);
  }
);
});

<ul id="menu" class="nav-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li id="top-menu"><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <ul id="submenu" class="sub-menu non-active">
        <li>US</li>
        <li>Our Style</li>
        <li>The Experience</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="top-menu"><a href="#">Galleries</a>
    </li>
    <ul id="submenu" class="sub-menu non-active">
        <li>Weddings</li>
        <li>Engagements</li>
        <li>Featured Weddings</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="top-menu"><a href="#">The Details</a>
    </li>
    <ul id="submenu" class="sub-menu non-active">
        <li>Investment</li>
        <li>Press and Awards</li>
        <li>Testimonials</li>
    </ul>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>The Blog</li>
</ul>

.nav-menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font: 24px'Playfair Display', Georgia, serif;
}
.navmenu ul li {
    margin:30px;
}
.non-active {
    display:none;
}
.active {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: First step, check errors in console.

Comment: Please could you briefly tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer your specific question but the same behavior can be easily achieved with css. This way you don't depend on javascript being turned on for standard menu access.

```css
ul.menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Galleries</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Gallery #1</li>
      <li>Gallery #2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Albums</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Album #1</li>
      <li>Album #2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

View on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmcPY)

Comment: Good mention.  Throw in some CSS3-Transitions for extra-bonus-points :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using hide and show wrong.
http://api.jquery.com/show/
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://jsfiddle.net/eXKV9/

```
$('#top-menu').hover(
  function () {
    $('#submenu').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('#submenu').hide();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be *unique*. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, jquery will not retrieve all the elements when you do $('#top-menu'), it'll only find the first element that matches the selector.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need to change the HTML a bit.  IDs are used only once on a page.  Classes are similar, but can be applied to any number of elements.  We also want to nest our sub-menu's under the top-menu.  That way the association is more clear.

```
<li class="top-menu"><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu non-active">
        <li>Ashley + David</li>
        <li>Our Style</li>
        <li>The Experience</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

We want to specify the nested sub-menu to show or hide.  `$(this)` refers to the top-menu that was hovered over.

```
$('.top-menu').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').show("slow");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').hide("slow");
  }
);
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N3TyT/6/)

Comment: This adds unnecessary animation and the dropdown ends up being unclickable because it disappears.

Comment: @user2151084, thanks.  I noticed something was off.  It appears to be fixed now by nesting the elements and slightly changing the jQuery usage.

Answer (score -1):

I updated your work. Is this what are trying to establish?

```
$('#top-menu').mouseover(function(){
    $('#submenu').addClass('active');
});
$('#top-menu').mouseout(function(){
    $('#submenu').removeClass('active');
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N3TyT/4/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was needing.  The others worked, but I eventually want the height of the menu to remain the same even with the dropdowns activated, so I needed a code that would let me modify the class.  Understand I just need to ensure unique ids to work throughout.  Thanks

Comment: (-1) The code doesn't work on drop downs after the first, and the answer needs formatting.  Please review the formatting guidelines.  I updated the post to show correct formatting.