# Responsive Side Navigation with a Drop Down

Tags: javascript

I have this coding for a menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/cssL313k/1/

```
<img onclick="Nav_open()" id="MobileMenu" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />

        <nav id="MobileNavigation" style="display: none">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Close" onclick="Nav_close()">Close X</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

         <script>
            function Nav_open() {
                document.getElementById("MobileNavigation").style.display =       "block";
            }
            function Nav_close() {
                document.getElementById("MobileNavigation").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
```

I need another menu to appear when you click "Services" below it and then go away when "Services" is clicked again.

I suck at javascript and I can't really find what I need via google, so anyone got ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript hover function for submenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308917/javascript-hover-function-for-submenu)

Comment: ...can't find what you need via google? Seriously?

Comment: If I could find what I wanted I wouldn't be here now would I?